# "(400) Bad Request" al intentar conectarse con Azure Storage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

Se me presentó un problema al intentar comunicarme a un servicio de almacenamiento Azure Storage, la comunicación la realizo desde un sitio web de Windows Azure a un contenedor Storage. Cuando se realiza la comunicación desde un sitio web local funciona perfectamente. He intentado actualizar las librerias de windows Storage Client, pero no se que podría ser.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muéstranos el código...

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow!, podrías poner un poco más de tu StackTrace? de hecho en lugar de la imagen aquí puedes insertar texto como código.

Comment: @Jeisson ¿Por qué revertiste las correciiones de ortografía y el título que se hicieron? En Stack Overflow casi cualquiera tiene la posibilidad de hacer ediciones a las preguntas y respuestas para mejorarlas.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz No es que accidentalmente oprimi el boton revertir desde mi celular. Podrias por favor reestablecer los cambios que realizaste. Yo anexare la informacion HTML del error como se me sugerio.Gracias.

Comment: @Jeisson ¡Listo!

Answer (score 3):

Los problemas de `BadRequest` con `Storage` vienen de la mano de la versión del paquete `Nuget` que estés utilizando en tu proyecto y la versión de la API pública del Storage.

Por lo general se recomienda actualizar a la última versión de [`WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), la 6.2.0 actualmente.

El motivo es que cuando lo pruebas local, posiblemente utilices el Storage Emulator, cuya interfaz suele ser de versiones más "viejas" que las que están online (a menos que mantengas tu Azure SDK actualizado), es posible que tu SDK funcione bien con ese emulador pero al momento de pasarlo a producción ya no funcione por la diferencia de versión de las APIs.

El Storage Emulator suele actualizarse con el [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/).

¡Espero haya ayudado!

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema se resolvió realizando la actualización de las librerias WindowsAzure.Storage como tu mencionas, también tuve que realizar esta actualización en los proyectos donde requería usar el blob store.

Comment: @Jeisson no olvides marcar el aporte de Matias Quaranta como respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Insisto en que es muy necesario mirar el código C# y el web.config / app.config.

### En desarrollo : Storage Emulator

El problema que planteas es recurrente porque en ambiente de desarrollo te debes estar conectando al  **Azure Storage Emulator**, que corre localmente, en un webrole los parámetros están preconfigurados para acceder al Emulador y por ello es posible que siempre te funcione, pero al publicar en la nube necesitas configurar el acceso correcto al storage account, y es allí donde debes tener el error.